# How to deserialize a Fixture JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize [this json](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/fixtures/133566).
First of all, I've used [json2charp](http://json2csharp.com/) for create the class.
I'm not sure, however, that the generated class is correct in this case.
However I made an Http request:

```
public string Request(string requestUrl)
{
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        string responseText;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        using (var responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return responseText;
}
```

With this function, I pass the link of deserialize from JSON, and I will return a string with the response.
At this point I save the response into a variable:

```
string responseText = parser.Request(requestUrl);
```

Then create an object containing the list of parameters defined in RootObject previously generated with the tool json2csharp.
The problem is that the foreach will not accept the item, saying that there is no definition of GetEnumerator.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fixtures.RootObject>(responseText);

        foreach (var element in obj)  //this insert the value into a Datagrid.
        { 
            MainWindow.AppWindow.Fixtures_Table.Items.Add(new Fixtures.Fixture
            {
                date = element.date;
                etc...
            });
        }
```

json structure:

```
fixture:": {
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/fixtures/133566"
        },
        "soccerseason": {
            "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/347"
        },
        "homeTeam": {
            "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/556"
        },
        "awayTeam": {
            "href": "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/514"
        }
    },
    "date": "2013-10-04T22:00:00Z",
    "matchday": 10,
    "homeTeamName": "Nimes Olympique",
    "awayTeamName": "SM Caen",
    "result": {
        "goalsHomeTeam": 2,
        "goalsAwayTeam": 1
    }
},
"head2head": {
    "count": 10,
    "timeFrameStart": "2014-05-12T22:00:00Z",
    "timeFrameEnd": "2000-09-29T22:00:00Z",
    "homeTeamWins": 1,
    "awayTeamWins": 5,
    "draws": 4,
    "lastHomeWinHomeTeam": { },
    "lastWinHomeTeam": { },
    "lastAwayWinAwayTeam": { },
    "lastWinAwayTeam": { },
    "fixtures": [ ]
}
}
```

So I want to know if I'm doing something wrong and if the generated class is good or not.
If someone else can deserialize the JSON in a more intelligent and effective, I am happy to read it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no enumerator because your JSON is nothing but objects instead of an array, so there is nothing to really iterate over unless you iterate over the keys to get the values. Therefore, I would expect Fixtures.RootObject to not be something implementing IEnumerable. If the generated RootObject follows your json, I would expect the following to work:

```
foreach (var element in obj.head2head.fixtures) { ... }
```

If not, I'd check out [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and deserialize the json into a dynamic or anonymous object to use the notation above.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseText);
foreach (var element in obj.head2head.fixtures) { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, I already use Json.net. So the class generate by json2csharp is good? I've update the question with the complete structure of json

Comment: Can you please post your generated class? We are just assuming based on the JSON what that class looks like, but really need to know to get you a better answer.

Comment: Sure, I paste the complete class on pastebin because the class is too long: http://pastebin.com/ceW98QV8

Comment: the first code sample should work fine then (`foreach (var element in obj.head2head.fixtures) { ... }`) - just make sure you're referencing properties of element based on the Fixture2 type from your pasted class.

Comment: @HaroldFinch, was this answer/comments able to help you? Please feel free to upvote/accept if so. I'm happy to elaborate on any of the details.